# I have a problem with OpenAL. I got this error message: no saved enable hardware sample rate converter preference found

Tags: c++, macos, openal

I am using Mac. I'm pretty new in OpenAL. When i try to run my code i get an error message: no saved enable hardware sample rate converter preference found.

I think that problem with alcOpenDevice() function. I don't know what to do with this. I tried to search the solution but i didn't find anything about that problem.

```
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>

int main()
{    

    ALCdevice *device;

    device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);

    ...

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where do you see this error message? What form does it take? How did you set up OpenAL? How did you build your program? What reference material are you using? Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm using Xcode. I see the error message in console output. When i try to build my project i see this: 2018-12-30 07:17:40.428315+0300 NAME_OF_MY_PROJECT[4240:98812]   no saved enable hardware sample rate converter preference found. I added OpenAL.framework to my project. Just simply press cmd+R. I watch some video about OpenAL on youtube.

Comment: I think this may be a Mac problem not an OpenAL problem

Comment: So, what i need to do?

Comment: I have no idea sorry! Good luck

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the replying.

Comment: After installing Mojave I'm getting the same console message, and I'm not even using any audio feature in my app other than `Hero` and `Basso` beeper sounds.